# Eclipse corrupts cvs files

Tags: eclipse, version-control, versioning, cvs, tortoisecvs

I'm facing a frustrating issue when creating a project from the resources I just checked from the cvs server . Basically everything is ok (all files are under version control) after the checkout is finished, but I soon as I import the project and Eclipse builds it , the CVS files content is deleted in almost each of the directory in the directory structure. Consequently the files are out of version control , and CVS sees them now as just added .

I used  both with TortoiseCVS, and WinCVS to check the projects out .

Any suggestion on how to fix this annoying problem would be greatly received. I tried everything I could think of.

Thanks !

Comment: Is there anything special about the content that's deleted, like it is the output folder of the compiler or anything?

Comment: I am seeing this problem too. I use the cvs plugin. I did File/New../Convert to C/C++ project. After that some of the folders had all the CVS directories deleted! I am checking out a non-eclipse cvs project and trying to make it a C/C++ project - but this keeps happening.

Comment: Is eclipse moving the project files into your workspace? What happens if you set your CVS folders write protected?